# How complex can you make your Hello World program?

Tags: cout

How complex can you get your Hello World code to be? From a simple cout, to a super intelligent AI, how creative can you get? Unleash your creativity!

Rules:

NO RULES. Go wild. Even machine code is fine.

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420264/convoluted-hello-world-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find great samples in any of the so called "Esoteric Programming Languages":
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language

e.g.: LOLCODE:

`HAI`
`CAN HAS STDIO?`
`VISIBLE "HAI WORLD!"`
`KTHXBYE`

Answer (score 3):

`C-x M-c M-butterfly`

Answer (score 1):

echo "3e25960a79dbc69b674cd4ec67a72c62"

Comment: **does not compute..** Care to explain this?

Comment: The complexity lies into the decoding of the information, this is the MD5 hash of *Hello world* via a bash command `echo -n "Hello world" | md5sum`

Answer (score 0):

This is a brainfcuk code:

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.
```